# Android is there any way to reuse a selector for button if the image including in the selector background changes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-selector

I am using the same background shape in a layer list for each button, then in that layer list a specific image related to the function of that button.

I know that I can create a selector for each button, however is there any way to reuse a selector and dynamically change the image (normal, focused and pressed all use the same image) for each button?

Even if there is no way to reuse a selector, are there any other good approaches for reuse and as opposed to creating 3 separate layer-list drawables and a selector for each button?

Cheers

EDIT: The button each have a text component

Answer (score 0):

use [ImageButton](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html&ei=U6d3UfbdNMn3rQeuuIDYAw&usg=AFQjCNF2XaiXbYKZKIoLE9ShfnIP2NPhmg&sig2=5smUHLrVvEFeGBjCdXhzGg&bvm=bv.45580626,d.bmk)

```
android:background="@drawable/yout_selector"
android:src="drawable/image"
```

Comment: Hmm, I shall have a look, however my buttons do contain text

Comment: oh for text you can't use it